# next previous preview slider navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have flat design where I am expected to code HTML and jquery. I need to code for a slider on navigation arrows when hovering on next arrow to show coming slide or previous arrow to show the previous slide how do I go about this in terms of HTML and java-script or jquery for more information please find the image on design I have.

Here is what I have tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>


        .prev, .next{
            background-color: #000000;
            padding: 12px;
            width: 60px;
            float: left;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .prev-content{
            background-color: beige;
            padding-left: 8px;
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
            height: 92px;
            display: none;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .next-content{
            background-color: beige;
            padding-left: 8px;
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
            height: 92px;
            margin-top: -37px;
/*            display: none;*/
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .con{
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top:40%;
        }

        .con-next, .next-content{
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top:40%;
        }
        .prev-content img, .next-content img{
            float: left;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }


    </style>

    <title>Siyandza ELP</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="con">
        <div class="prev">
            <img src="images/left-arrow.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="prev-content">
            <p><img src="images/image.png" width="40"/> Previous<br />Learning Object Title<br />PDF</p>
        </div>        
    </div><!-- end prev prev -->

    <!-- SCRIPTS **********************-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript">

        $(".prev").hover(function(){
            $('.prev-content').show();
            },function(){
                $('.prev-content').hide();
            });


    </script>
<!--    <script src="js/sandile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you required to build your own slider or can you use one that's already been built? This is quite a large project you've taken on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the basic using pure javascript

```js
    function setScr (){
      imageLeft.setAttribute("src",imageArray[i-1]);
      sliderWrapper.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageArray[i] + ')';
      imageRight.setAttribute("src",imageArray[i+1]);
    }

    var i=0,
        main = document.querySelector("main"),
        imageArray =["http://placekitten.com/500/200","http://placekitten.com/501/200","http://placekitten.com/500/201","http://placekitten.com/499/200","http://placekitten.com/400/600"],
        sliderWrapper= document.createElement("figure"),
        sliderArrowLeft = document.createElement("div"),
        sliderArrowRight = document.createElement("div"),
        imageArrayLength = imageArray.length,
        imageLeft = document.createElement("img"),
        imageRight= document.createElement("img"),
        figureLeft = document.createElement("figure"),
        figureRight= document.createElement("figure");

    sliderWrapper.classList.add("slider-wrapper");
    sliderArrowLeft.classList.add("sliderArrowLeft","arrow");
    sliderArrowRight.classList.add("sliderArrowRight","arrow");

    imageLeft.setAttribute("src","undefined");
    imageRight.setAttribute("src",imageArray[i+1]);

    figureLeft.appendChild(imageLeft);
    figureRight.appendChild(imageRight);

    sliderArrowLeft.appendChild(figureLeft);
    sliderArrowRight.appendChild(figureRight);

    sliderWrapper.appendChild(sliderArrowLeft);
    sliderWrapper.appendChild(sliderArrowRight);

    main.appendChild(sliderWrapper);
    sliderWrapper.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageArray[i] + ')';

    document.querySelectorAll(".arrow").forEach(function(e){

    e.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(imageArray[i-1],i,imageArray[i+1]);
        if(this.classList.contains("sliderArrowLeft") && i > 0){
            i--;setScr ()
        }if(this.classList.contains("sliderArrowRight") && i < imageArrayLength -1){
            i++;setScr ()
        }else{return false}
      
    }, false);

    });
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.slider-wrapper{
  width: 650px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #ebebeb;
  background-size:cover;
  border: 2px solid brown
}

.arrow img[src="undefined"]{
  opacity:0
}
.sliderArrowRight{
  right: 0;
}
.sliderArrowLeft, .sliderArrowRight{
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: black;
  background-size:cover;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  overflow:hidden
}
.sliderArrowLeft figure, .sliderArrowRight figure, .sliderArrowLeft:hover, .sliderArrowRight:hover{
  width: 250px;
}
.sliderArrowLeft figure, .sliderArrowRight figure{
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%
}
.sliderArrowLeft figure{
  float: left
}
.sliderArrowRight figure{
  float: right
}
.sliderArrowLeft img, .sliderArrowRight img{
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px; 
}
.sliderArrowLeft img{
    margin: 10px 0 0 116px;
}
.sliderArrowRight img{
    margin: 10px 0 0 12px;
  }
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Now you can play with [overflow:hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: thanks it working, but not effective as it gives me index.html:117 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You dont really have to use any javascript to achive this. 
Just add this between your css tags.

```
.con:hover .prev-content{ display:block}
```

Both your arrow and the content remains in the same container. So that whenever you hover to that container, the .prev-content will show.

Using CSS for these kind of interactions improve your sites performance in a tremendous amount. The more script you use, the heavier your site will get.